# How to get list of currently instantiated instances of some dependency in Castle Windsor?

Tags: c#, castle-windsor, ioc-container

Suppose I have a component `Bar` that does `Foo` and notifies about that calling `FooHappened` method on all services implementing `IFooConsumer` interface.

I can write `Bar` like this

```
class Bar
{
    public Bar(IEnumerable<IFooConsumer> fooConsumers) { ... }

    public void Foo()
    {
        // foo-ing
        foreach (var f in _fooConsumers) f.FooHappened();
    }
}
```

It will work, but instantiating `Bar` will instantiate all possible `IFooConsumer`s. What if I need to notify only those `IFooConsumer`s that exist at the moment when `Foo` happened?

Is there a way to get some kind of tracker that knows about all instantiated instances of `IFooConsumer`?

I could probably write one myself via subscribing to `IWindsorContainer.Kernel.ComponentCreated`, but I'm interested if something like that exists? Or maybe there's another way to solve my issue?

Comment: I would say you should avoid having the subscribers of an object's event be dependencies of the object. If you are trying to notify listeners of events you should have a separate subscriber mechanism. For example to correlate listener instances with a `FooHappened` event, declare a `FooHappenedHandler` method delegate on `Bar` and set it to a method on your listeners. Then call `FooHappened(this)` inside `Foo()` which will allow the code defined by the listeners to execute.

Comment: @moarboilerplate that mechanism implementation given a Castle Windsor is a question actually. Having event or event-like mechanism is a possibility, but will require explicit subscription/unsubscription to avoid memory leaks. Container already watches for objects lifetimes internally, so I thought it might have something ready-to-use here.

Comment: You can take a look at Caliburn.Micro EventAggregator. That can integrate nicely with Castle.Windsor. You could role something similair. Take a look at this link (https://github.com/marwijn/Caliburn.Micro.Windsor/blob/master/content/Bootstrap/EventRegistrationFacility.cs.pp) for the integration with windsor.

Comment: @Marwijn, you should propose your comment as a solution, I didn't know using a facility would be this simple (at least it looks this way from what i've seen)

Comment: @samy I've posted it as a  solution, facilties are really powerfull, yet simple once you've find the right hook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a simple facility like the one showing below, that will do the event registration every time a components get's instantiated. The code below here is for using Winsor with Caliburn.Micro. This will also make sure that events get deregistered, which will otherwise result in weird behaviour. In your case I would not have Bar directly fire the event's to all the classes, but rather use a singleton component (like IEventAggregator below) to fire events to multiple classes. This will also make sure that events get deregistered, which will otherwise result in weird behaviour. In the code every class that derives from IHandle will receive events. You can change this according to your needs.

If you have any questions just let me know.

```
class EventRegistrationFacility : AbstractFacility
{
    private IEventAggregator _eventAggregator;
    protected override void Init()
    {
        Kernel.ComponentCreated += ComponentCreated;
        Kernel.ComponentDestroyed += ComponentDestroyed;
    }

    void ComponentCreated(Castle.Core.ComponentModel model, object instance)
    {
        if (!(instance is IHandle)) return;
        if (_eventAggregator == null) _eventAggregator = Kernel.Resolve<IEventAggregator>();
        _eventAggregator.Subscribe(instance);
    }

    void ComponentDestroyed(Castle.Core.ComponentModel model, object instance)
    {
        if (!(instance is IHandle)) return;
        if (_eventAggregator == null) return;
        _eventAggregator.Unsubscribe(instance);
    }

}
```

===EDIT====

Combining this with the bouncer as described by Sammy:

```
public interface IBouncer {
    IEnumerable<IFooConsumer> WhoIsInside {get;}
    void WelcomeTo(IFooConsumer consumer);
    void EscortOut(IFooConsumer consumer);
}

public class Bouncer {
    private IList<IFooConsumer> _inside {get;}
    void WelcomeTo(IFooConsumer consumer) {
        _inside.Add(consumer);
}
    void EscortOut(IFooConsumer consumer);
        _inside.Remove(consumer);
    }
    IEnumerable<IFooConsumer> WhoIsInside {
        get {
            return _inside;
        }
    }



public Consumer: IFooConsumer {
    FooHappened() {
        // Do something.
}
    // no need to implement constructor/dispose
}


class Bar
{
    public Bar(IBouncer bouncer) { ... }

    public void Foo()
    {
        // foo-ing ==> alernatively create a function on Bouncer that does this. And keep WhoIsInside private.
        foreach (var f in bouncer.WhoIsInside) f.FooHappened();
    }
}


class BouncerRegistrationFacility : AbstractFacility
{
    private IBouncer _bouncer
    protected override void Init()
    {
        Kernel.ComponentCreated += ComponentCreated;
        Kernel.ComponentDestroyed += ComponentDestroyed;
    }

    void ComponentCreated(Castle.Core.ComponentModel model, object instance)
    {
        if (!(instance is IFooConsumer)) return;
        if (_bouncer == null) _bouncer = Kernel.Resolve<IEventAggregator>();
        _bouncer.WelcomeTo(instance);
    }

    void ComponentDestroyed(Castle.Core.ComponentModel model, object instance)
    {
        if (!(instance is IFooConsumer)) return;
        if (_bouncer == null) return;
        _bouncer.EscortOut(instance);
    }
}
```

Allthough you need some more code for writing the facility, there is no need for FooConsumers to register/unregister themselves. As the registration code must originally be written in all FooConsumers it tends to repeat. In this way the subscription/unsubscription is done as a commission/decommission requirement and only needs to be dealt with once.

P.S. Code is written in notepad and might contain compile errors.

Comment: If it is not too much hassle, could you show an example of how one would use the facility with the Bar class? I think I have nailed it down mentally (Bar and EventRegistrationFacility both point to the same component which is used to distribute the call) but I'd like to be sure

Answer (score 1):

I think that putting the crux of knowing which objects are instantiated on Castle Windsor is not the best way forward; you will certainly need to access some container methods and doing so will link your components to Castle, which shouldn't happen.

What I'd recommend instead is to create a component `IBouncer`. That component would be injected as singleton in all `IFooConsumer` which would call it upon being created and disposed (dispose being one option, you could use other methods)

```
public interface IBouncer {
     IEnumerable<IFooConsumer> WhoIsInside {get;}
     void WelcomeTo(IFooConsumer consumer);
     void EscortOut(IFooConsumer consumer);
}

public Consumer: IFooConsumer {
    public Consumer(IBouncer bouncer) {
        bouncer.WelcomeTo(this);
    }

    public Dispose() {
        bouncer.EscortOut(this); // dispose pattern ommitted
    }
}
```

Now instead of passing the list of `IFooConsumer` to your `Bar`, just add the `IBouncer` to it and ask which consumers are inside.

```
class Bar
{
    public Bar(IBouncer bouncer) { ... }

    public void Foo()
    {
        // foo-ing
        foreach (var f in bouncer.WhoIsInside) f.FooHappened();
    }
}
```

Comment: Feel free to change names: the bouncer / bar association happened to me, and my brain wouldn't let go of the bad joke if I didn't put it out to rest

Comment: +1. That's another way to implement it. Though, my components with business logic won't know about container - I was talking about some generic extension to windsor container itself - a facility probably, that is able to track instances of requested types. And then configure some interface like `IInstanceTracker<T>` that `Bar` would depend onto in the similar way as abstract factories are configured with `TypedFactoryFacility`. It would be basically the same as your `IBouncer` here. But your way is easier to understand for newcomers for sure :)